# mkdir: missing operand when doing sudo over ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, mkdir

I am trying to create directory with sudo user permission over SSH.

Here is the command i formed

`some_command "ssh -t userA@host bash -c \"\'sudo -u userB bash -c \" mkdir -p /home/userB/dir_to_create \" \'\" "`

here `some_command` is part of `expect` script.

I am getting this error :-

```
[sudo] password for userB:
mkdir: missing operand
Try `mkdir --help' for more information.
Connection to host closed.
```

If i run 
`sudo -u userB bash -c "mkdir /home/userB/dir_to_create"`

it works.

Comment: Are you required to use all those `bash -c` constructs? You don't need it with ssh and only need it with sudo if sudo is configured to allow `bash` and not allow arbitrary commands, which would be uncommon.

Comment: What's wrong with `ssh userA@host 'sudo -u userB mkdir /home/userB/dir_to_create'`?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks man. It worked. I tried your way and worked like charm. Can you write that one as answer so i can accept it . Thanks again. 
here is what i did :- `spawn bash -c "ssh -t userA@host \"sudo -u userB bash -c 'mkdir -p /home/userB/perf_tools' \" "`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comment from [Mark Plotnick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2554472/mark-plotnick) , i figured out the answer .

Here is the solution to it

```
spawn bash -c "ssh -t userA@host \"sudo -u userB bash -c 'mkdir -p /home/userB/perf_tools' \" "
```

Trick is that , single quote and double quote placements make all the magic happen in this script.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh -t user@host "bash -c \"sudo -u otherUser bash -c 'mkdir -p /home/userB/dir_to_create'\""
```

should work

Comment: can you check my edited question? I want to wrap whole thing in another command .